# Kendo grid inline editing submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Here, I create kendo grid inline editing, then there is field outside the grid that contains data that needs to insert with the other data in the grid. Is it possible to submit data from the grid and external form (field) together? Does anyone have an idea? [DEMO](https://dojo.telerik.com/EvEMUDeF)

> Javascript

```
create: {
                url:  "./getAccommodation.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: function () {
                        return {
                            method: "addAccommodation",
                        }
                    },
                complete: function (e) {  
                            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                          }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a property in the model for that value, after that you can use parameterMap to set that property to a value outside the grid.

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read" && options) {
                            options.YourProp= "external value";
                            return kendo.stringify(options);
                        }
                    }
```